# How to pass Json string as a javascript method parameter

Tags: javascript, json

I formed a Json String.

```
var jsonProduct = "{Product:'" + Details[0] + "',Brand:'" + Details[1] + "',Model:'" + Details[2] + "',Price:'" + Details[3] + "'}"

<input class="button black" type="submit" value="Add To Cart" onclick="return addOrderItem(' + jsonProduct + ')" />
```

How to pass this 'jsonproduct to javascript function addOrderItem as follows

```
function addOrderItem(product)
{
    cartproduct[cartproduct.length] =  " + product + ";
    //cartproduct[cartproduct.length] = " + {Product:'1001',Brand:Dell',Model:'Inspiron',Price:'25000'} + ";
}
```

When I pass product as parameter it is not working

Comment: Why are you handling the click on a submit input ? Don't you want to handle the submit event on the form instead ?

Answer (score 4):

You could parse it using

```
var product = JSON.parse(jsonProduct);
```

but you don't have to use JSON at all. Do this :

```
var product = {
    Product: Details[0], Brand:Details[1],
    Model:Details[2], Price:Details[3]
};
addOrderItem(product);
```

If you want to call this from an input click, you can bind the call using

```
onclick="return addOrderItem(product)"
```

or, better, give an id to your element and then bind the event handler from the JS code :

```
<input id=submit class="button black" type="submit" value="Add To Cart">
<script>
    document.getElementById('submit').onclick=function(){addOrderItem(product)};
</script>
```